# Android service being killed very quickly

Tags: android, service

I am developing an application that makes use of a Service. The Service itself works, but the Android systems kills it within 30 seconds of exiting my Activity, sometimes as early as 6 seconds.

I've had a look at a lot of different posts regarding this and know that I can use a foreground service with an icon. At this stage I don't want to go down this path.

I am explicitly starting the service with the following code. The service is controlled by a SwitchPreference.
The service also returns START_STICKY so it does get restarted.

This is the code I am using (not run together like this).

```
// starting within the activity
Intent intent = new Intent(context, ListenerService.class);
startService(intent);

// stopping within the activity
Intent intent = new Intent(context, ListenerService.class);
stopService(intent);

// Service onStartCommand
return START_STICKY;
```

When I exit the application the first time, I see the activity being destroyed and then within 30 seconds I see my toast message displayed stating that the service has been restarted.

I understand that the Android system has every right to kill my service when memory is low, but should I expect it to be killed almost immediately after I exit my application?
Is it just garbage collecting my activity references and starting the service "clean"?

I am cleaning up objects in my onStop() method of the activity.

Also, when I return into my application via the activity, is it good practice to bind to the service to get a reference to the service object?
The binding is completed in onStart() method of the activity as follows:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ListenerService.class);
bindService(intent, serviceConnection, 0);
```

Unbinding is completed in the onStop() method

```
unbindService(serviceConnection);
```

So 2 questions:
 
1. Should I expect the Android system to kill and restart my service almost immediately?
2. Is my binding methodology acceptable?

Many thanks

Comment: Use broadcast receiver with service.

Comment: Do you call stopSelf or stopService command from anywhere? If server called stopSelf for each started command then it has nothing to do and it can be destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

From what i understand you are controlling the lifecycle of your service through your activity by calling startService and stopService. Is this correct?

If you want to keep the service running why are you calling stopService on it?

Regarding the rebooting of the service - everything depends on your service configuration, and your code implementation.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback so far. I have a broadcast receiver registered in the service....depending on what the user will select. During my testing I definitely have the broadcast receiver (incoming sms) registered and the service is still restarted not long after exiting the application.

Comment: I don't call selfStop at all. startService and stopService are controlled by the user via a SwitchPreference. The SwitchPreference is definitely on and the service started when Android kills and restarts the service.